# fdm & msmtp: mark messages read

Tags: email

I have installed `fdm` and `offlineimap` to connect to our corporate Exchange server. Now I want an action that marks a message read when a pattern matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to move and mark:

```
action "processed"       maildir  "%h/Mails/work/INBOX.Processed"
# Found here: https://github.com/nicm/fdm/blob/master/examples/f-terbeck.conf
action "mark-read"       exec     'mf="%[mail_file]"; mv "${mf}" "${mf%%/*}/../cur/${mf##*/}:2,S"'

match "^From:.*test@xyz\.de"     in headers actions { "processed" "mark-read" }
```